# What's the easiest way to programmatically find the latest Qt version number?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.4

I need to automatically check, if my systems are running the latest released Qt version. In my software I use `QT_VERSION_STR` to get the compile version of Qt.

But how can I determine the latest released version in a python script? For Wordpress, there is a fancy [API call](https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.6/). Does someone know an equivalent for Qt?

Comment: Nope, C++. The "python script" part is not relevant. It could be tested by Bash as well.

Comment: Maybe you need to dig how Qt Maintenance Tool searches for updated components.

Answer (score 3):

Query the latest tag from git repository:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags https://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git \
| awk '{print $2}' \
| grep -v '\^{}$' \
| grep -v '-' \
| sort | tail -1 \
| awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print a[3]}'
```

Comment: This shows the installed version. I need the available version, that is released on the web.

Comment: Fancy. I think this will show me a `5.4.2-rc1` before 5.4.2 is released, so it might be necessary to additionally grep for lines without "-"